# Principal Ideal Ring and ID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility

In definition of PID, if we take ring instead of ID call it PIR. I add one more condition: all generators of an ideal are associate to each other. Would it imply PIR with this condition is PID?

Definition: $a$ and $b$ are associate if there exist a unit $u$ such that $au = ua =1$. (Note I am not assuming commutativity also in definition.)

PID: A ring with no zero divisor and all ideals generated by single element.

Comment: Okay but what if I don't assume this in definition of PID. or if you like call it by some other name. @user26857

Comment: Your definition of "$a$ and $b$ are associate" amounts to "$a$ is a unit." I assume you mistyped something... maybe the $1$ should be a $b$?

Comment: In your definition of PIR, only *two-sided* ideals are principal?

Answer (score 2):

Let consider $R=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

This ring is obviously not a domain and has $2$  proper ideals:

- $(2)=(4)$ and $[4]=[2][5]$, so the two generators are associated (I supose you will write $ua=au=b$).
- $(3)$, that could be generated only by $3$

Now this ring satisfies your hypothesis (if I well understand what you need) but is obviously not a PID.

Comment: @user26857 If you look closer, my main issue was correcting the grammar ("not obviously" vs "obviously not") whereas yours was for spelling only...